# how to sort using shell script

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, ubuntu

```
        clear
echo "==========================================="
echo "  Top 5 Best Seller"
echo "-------------------------------------------"
echo ""

printf "${UL}$(tput bold)%-40s\t%-20s\t%-10s\t%-20s\t%-5s\t%-10s$(tput sgr0)\n\n" "Title" "Author" "Price" "Qty Available" "Sold" "Total Sales"

IFS=:
while read FIRST SECOND THIRD FOURTH FIFTH
do
    SALES=$(echo $THIRD*$FIFTH | bc)
    printf "%-40s\t%-20s\t%-10s\t%-20s\t%-5s\t%-10s\n" "$FIRST" "$SECOND" "\$$THIRD" "$FOURTH" "$FIFTH" "\$$SALES"
done < BookDB.txt | sort -t: -n -k5 -r BookDB.txt
```

when my file look like this :

```
All About Ubuntu:Ubuntu Team:76.00:55:133
Catch Me If You Can:Mary Ann:23.60:6:2
Happy Day:Mary Ann:12.99:197:101
```

I cant seems to get it to be arrange like this
output should be some thing like this:

```
Title                                       Author                  Price       Qty Available           Sold    Total Sales
All About Ubuntu                            Ubuntu Team             $76.00      55                      133     $10108.00 
Happy Day                                   Mary Ann                $12.99      197                     101     $1311.99         
Catch Me If You Can                         Mary Ann                $23.60      6                       2       $47.20
```

Comment: Why not just `sort -t: -n -k4 -r file`? It works to me, considering you want to sort on 4th col, etc.

Comment: i'm doing using gedit. it cant seems to sort the qty sold

Comment: @fedorqui any other way?

Comment: @fedorqui lets say if i want to remove the ":" in the result what should i do?

Comment: Please update indicating what is your desired output. Otherwise it is difficult to know what you mean.

Comment: @fedorqui   output should be arrange neatly according to 
Title      Author      Price     Qty Ava    Sold    Total Price